# Adding a third parameter to an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, get

Im doing a GET request with some parameters in the url like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/testing.php?url=http://www.bbc.co.uk&item[][variable1_]=variable2_
```

Then in my PHP file I process like this:

```
$url = filter_var(($_GET['url']), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$_GET = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$mArray = $_GET['item'];

 foreach ($mArray as $aValue) {
  foreach ($aValue as $key => $value) {

 echo "$key $value <br> 
       $key $value <br>"; 

  }
 }
```

This outputs:

```
variable1_variable2_
variable1_variable2_
```

Now I need to insert a third parameter in the URL somehow and echo it out with the other parameters. So I want to echo like this:

```
echo "$key $value $other_value<br> 
      $key $value $other_value<br>";
```

And this will output:

```
variable1_variable2_other_value_
variable1_variable2_other_value_
```

My question is: what do I have to change in the URL im sending in order to add this third variable? Or do I have to change the foreach code? I can't find anything on the internet.

Comment: I wish PHP never implemented this functionality. In my opinion, if you need to pass data in this manner, you should be using POST.

Comment: @crush You can't bookmark POST:)

Comment: What's that third variable? Why do you need it?
I don't really understand your question...

Comment: @Ofir Baruch Why does it matter I just need it for my code

Comment: It does matter. How is it possible to give you an answer of "where should I put a variable" if you don't know where are you getting it from?

Comment: Set the url to be: `&item[][variable1_]=variable2_&third=blabla`.
And then, after: `echo "$key $value<br>$key $value <br>";` add `echo $_GET['third'];`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Why should you need to bookmark a URL that passes an array in this manner?

Comment: @Ofir Baruch That will output `variable1_variable2_
variable1_variable2_blabla` I need it to be `variable1_variable2_blabla
variable1_variable2_blabla`

Comment: @crush I just need it that way for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the values as a URL encoded JSON string, and then parse that out with your PHP.  Then, you could build your structure as you wish.  Of course, it would work best with a post, but if you need something to bookmark, this would work.

For instance, if your data that you want to pass looks like this:

```
[{"url":"http://www.google.com"}, {"variable1_":"variable2_", "variable3_":"variable4_"}]
```

You would build the URL like this:

```
url.com?data=%5B%7B%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%22%2C%20%7B%22variable1_%22%3A%22variable2_%22%2C%20%22variable3_%22%3A%22variable4_%22%7D%5D
```